# Splash screen showing perfect for ios7.1 but not for ios6.1 in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, orientation, splash-screen

I am having an app which is in Landscape Mode.

I have given splash screens for my app with size of 2048 * 1536 and 1024 * 768.

It is showing perfect for ios 7.1 as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

But when I run the app in ios 6.1 it shows like the screenshot below.

[image]

This is how my plist is and my settings from my project navigators.

[image]

[image]

I tried to change my settings from plist but not working.

How to solve this issue?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select Target > Lunch Images > Use Assest Catlog

Then You See Dialog box Then Choose Migrate Option

top right corner click on the 'Attribute Inspector' icon. Here you can set the Target OS for the Launch Images.Uncheck Portrait Option.

Comment: Superb answer. Working fine.+1